# How to implement Google map V2 with voice navigation in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to implement voice navigation in android google map v2, is it possible to implement route navigation or is there any way to implement this functionality? I have displayed route from source to destination and I'm searching to implement route navigation.

Answer (score 0):

The return JSON or XML contains HTML_Instruction for each step, convert the html to text, use the text with [Text to speech](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) function, Will require some tracking method to make sure that your voice navigation is telling the right instruction regards to the current step.

Hope it help
Good luck